# Maui - Define Activity in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, maui

I am trying to define the MainActivity within the AndroidManifest.xml using MAUI.

I have a Solution, named "A.B.C", and a MAUI project in it named "D".
Within the D.csproj file, I have

```
 <RootNamespace>D</RootNamespace>
 <ApplicationTitle>D</ApplicationTitle>
 <ApplicationId>A.B.C.D</ApplicationId>
```

My attempts were in adding to the AndroidManifest.xml the following:

```
<manifest ...>
  <application ...>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity", android:exported=true>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I had also tried, setting the activity's `android:name` to equal "A.B.C.D.Platforms.Android.MainActivity" or "D.Platforms.Android.MainActivity".

Also I tried giving the Activity a name and then use in the manifest, but without a success.

The error I got is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
A.B.C.D/A.B.C.D.MainActivity" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "A.B.C.D.MainActivity"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am trying to persist a permission given to a usb device connected to an android , by including within the activity an "intent-filter"

Comment: Is there any latest progress?

Comment: Earlier in the lifetime of this question there was a complaint that the post was too short on detail to fully answer. Following a productive discussion in a chatroom it has been established that the question is OK, so I am agreeing with a SME that it would be best reopened.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to work, it's going to be `D.MainActivity`, not `.MainActivity`.

Comment: I have [moved this discussion to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254957/discussion-between-halfer-and-h-a-h).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution without the manifest

```
[Activity( Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", 
           Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", 
           Name = "com.package.name.MainActivity",
           MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{...}
```

Setting the "Name" attribute sets the name of the activity.
To control the behaviour test it with ADB.

```
adb connect IP_OF_YOUR_DEVICE
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/.MainActivity
```

With those commands you should be able to start the app.

I really hope this helps you with your problem